# Date format in WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm working with a theme in WordPress using a date picker.
The date shows as : MM dd, YY and i'd like dd MM YY.

I searched for these terms but i have some infos in WordPress core, theme, plugins and woocommerce.

I replaced all the MM dd, YY by dd MM YY but it still shows the US format.

http://www.iaci.be/property/maison-10-chambres-a-vendre-wepion/

Here's the code in the theme :

```
<?php
$date_published = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),             
?>
<div class="mkdf-title-inline-part">
<?php echo esc_html($date_published); ?>
</div>
```

Any idea for making this change?

Answer (score 0):

The date and time format are set by the *user* in Settings/General, in the admin area.  So the configuration of each site can be different, and you shouldn't be touching the code.

Comment: The Settings/General is set on french as i want. But it doesn't work in the theme.

Comment: Then you might consider a theme upgrade :-)

Comment: Ow ow... I'be been too dumb on this one... I wanted to modify dates but they were stored in a DB as text. I tried a new input and Boom, it works... Thanks!

Comment: it's easy to get confused :-).  Glad it's working for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<?php
$date_published = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "date");            
$date_published = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date_published));
?>
```

See quick fiddle i made [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfdfe9331bd3d7d9369d98a477f3fa2633e3085d).